# Printing char as integer

Tags: c

```
int main(){
    char a = 65;
    a=a+5;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

I would think that I at least get a warning that I am trying to print `%d` but the variable is `char`

Why there is no problem to print this way?

Comment: The `char` is promoted to `int` when passed to a variadic function such as `printf`. It is an integer type, so it is a number (as you assigned to it). Aside: note that `'A'` is of type `int` not `char`.

Comment: Because the manual says so: `c      If no l modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written.`

Comment: @WeatherVane when will I get an error or a warning? with different types?

Comment: @wildplasser That's for `%c`, not `%d`

Comment: You won't get a warning. The compiler doesn't know your intention. You won't get one with the converse `printf("%c\n", 65);` either. But with incompatible types you might, such as passing `float` to `%d`, but there is no obligation on the compiler to warn you.

Comment: @GovindParmar: oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Largely for historic reasons, characters are small integers, and all integer arithmetic is done in the `int` type or wider. Software sometimes had to work with characters as integer codes and sometimes as things to be printed, so C developed with the `char` type being flexible.

Wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used in an expression, including function arguments, you may use a `char` instead.

If we were designing the language anew, we might distinguish `char`-as-character from `char`-as-integer and require explicit conversions to convert between them. However, the language is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

> I would think that I at least get a warning that I am trying to print `%d` but the variable is `char`

"there is no problem" because `"%d"` expected an `int` and `a` was converted to an `int` when passed to `printf()`.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445849/printing-char-as-integer/54446092#comment95700925_54445849)

---

**Default argument
promotions**

Because `a` is passed to `printf(const char *, ...)`as a `...` argument:

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.  C11dr §6.5.2.2 7

The *default argument
promotion* of a `char` converts it into an `int`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or `unsigned` when `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.
(Example: exceptional platforms where `char, int` are the same bit width and sign-ness.)

Comment: The same occur with
'int main(){
    char a = 65;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}'

Comment: the printf has a prototype